# PHP If URL Issue

Tags: php

Ok I have an issue with an if php command.

```
{php}
$searchloadpage = "/search/Car/";
$listingloadpage = "/listing/%";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($searchloadpage==$currentpage) { 
include('searchload.php');
}
if($listingloadpage==$currentpage) { 
include('searchload.php');
} else {

}
{/php}
```

Now the questions is how do you make it so with the $listingloadpage = "/listing/HERE"  the HERE part I need to make it so that anything that is after listing it will take.

Example: /listing/1222.html or any thing that is after /listing/ it will load my searchload.php file.  I think its called an wildcard code where the php will think /listing/and any thing after this listing directory.

Hope that was clear. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

```
$listingloadpage = "/listing/";
if (stristr($currentpage, $listingloadpage) !== false) {
  ...
```

That will work if `/listing/` appears anywhere in the url. If you need it at the start:

```
if (stristr($currentpage, $listingloadpage) === 0) {
```

Note that I have removed the `%` character from your string.

Answer (score 0):

You sould use the regex to validate /listing/123.html, listing/abc.html, listing/abc...

```
<?php
    $searchloadpage = "/search/Car/";
    $listingloadpage = "/\/listing\/.+/";

    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if($searchloadpage == $currentpage) {
        include('searchload.php');

    } else if (preg_match($listingloadpage, $currentpage)) {
        include('searchload.php');

    // something else
    } else {

    }
?>
```

And, for example, if you only want /listing/123.html and not /listing/somethingelse, you'd want:

```
$listingloadpage = "/\/listing\/[0-9]+\.html/";
```